# document.write will not show output

Tags: javascript

When i write array element it will not show output when i click asending and desending no output will be printed....plese check my query if fault in it ...i think function is stop working when i click button it nothing show me

```
     <html>
   <TITLE>Javascript Arrays</TITLE> 
   <BODY bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
   <h1>Implementation of Sort and Reverse Functions </h>     
     <h2>Enter number of Elements</h2>
      <form name="Anonymous Ghost">
     <INPUT type="number" name="takeinput" id="valueField" size="30">
       <Input type="button" name="name1" value="Take Input" onClick="a()"> </form>
     <form name="Anonymous Ghost">
     <Input type="button" name="name2" value="Ascending" onClick="b()">
     <Input type="button" name="name3" value="Descending" onClick="c()">
      </form>

          </BODY>
        <SCRIPT>
     function a() {
         var val = parseInt(document.getElementById('valueField').value)
             var words = new Array(val);
          for (k = 0; k < words.length; k = k + 1) {
    words[k] = window.prompt("Enter String # " + k, "");
           }
          }

        function b() {
       words.sort( ) ;
       document.write( "SORTED WORDS:" + "<BR>" ) ;
      for ( k = 0 ; k < words.length ; k = k + 1 ) {
      document.write( words[ k ] + "<BR>" ) ;
       }
      }

         function c() {
       words.sort( ) ;
        words.reverse( ) ;
       document.write( "SORTED WORDS:" + "<BR>" ) ;
       for ( k = 0 ; k < words.length ; k = k + 1 ) {
         document.write( words[ k ] + "<BR>" ) ;
         }
         }
         </SCRIPT>
       </HEAD>
        <BODY>
      </BODY>
             </HTML>
```

Comment: 'words' is a local variable of your 'a' function. It's undefined in both 'b' and 'c'. So an easy fix is to define 'words' as a global variable.

Comment: Do you _really_ format your code like this? What a horrendous mess!

Comment: Please format your code.Your editor should have an option for that.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `words` in function `a()` scope so it's not accessible out of that scope.
Modify your code defining `words` in global scope and remove the `var` keyword in function `a()` so it wont override the global `words`

Your code should be like this:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Javascript Arrays</title> 
    </head> 
    <body bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
        <h1>Implementation of Sort and Reverse Functions </h1>     
        <h2>Enter number of Elements</h2>
        <form name="Anonymous Ghost">
        <INPUT type="number" name="takeinput" id="valueField" size="30" />
        <Input type="button" name="name1" value="Take Input" onClick="a()" />
        </form>
        <form name="Anonymous Ghost">
        <Input type="button" name="name2" value="Ascending" onClick="b()" />
        <Input type="button" name="name3" value="Descending" onClick="c()" />
        </form>
    </body>
    <script>
        var words;
        function a() {
            var val = parseInt(document.getElementById('valueField').value);
            words = new Array(val);
            for (k = 0; k < words.length; k = k + 1) {
                words[k] = window.prompt("Enter String # " + k, "");
            }
        }

        function b() {
            words.sort( ) ;
            document.write( "SORTED WORDS:" + "<BR>" ) ;
            for ( k = 0 ; k < words.length ; k = k + 1 ) {
                document.write( words[ k ] + "<BR>" ) ;
            }
        }

        function c() {
            words.sort( ) ;
            words.reverse( ) ;
            document.write( "SORTED WORDS:" + "<BR>" ) ;
            for ( k = 0 ; k < words.length ; k = k + 1 ) {
                document.write( words[ k ] + "<BR>" ) ;
            }
        }
    </script>
    </html>
```

PS : You can use developer tools in your browser to inspect errors in Javascripts console.

PS2: Keep your code tidy and clean.